# How can I avoid this use of "eval" in Perl?

Tags: perl, eval

I have code like this:

```
my @e = ( '($i,$j, $k,$l)',  '($i,$k, $j,$l)',  '($i,$l, $j,$k)',
          '($j,$k, $i,$l)',  '($j,$l, $i,$k)',  '($k,$l, $i,$j)'
        );
#
# Assign various sets of values to $i,$j,$k,$l
#
        foreach ( @e ) {
          my ($a,$b, $c,$d) = eval $_;
#
# Do calculations based on the values of $a,$b,$c,$d
#
```

It all works as I intended. But it feels clumsy to use eval like this. I feel there must be a better way of looping over those six permutations of the four values.  I've tried various ways, but found nothing that worked, so I fell back on using eval.

Comment: Any good reason for not using array references?

Comment: These aren't even all permutations of the four variables. What are you trying to achieve? In most cases a string eval is a bad idea, and this certainly is not an exception. As Dada said, references would work here, or you could calculate all the permutations. But you will have to tell us what you're after first.

Comment: See also [Algorithm::Permute](https://metacpan.org/pod/Algorithm::Permute)

Comment: Besides not using `eval` in this horrible way, you should also avoid using `$a` and `$b`, as they are reserved variables used in `sort()`. I feel certain that many things in your code probably needs reworking.

Comment: I would be using array references, but I've failed to find a way to get them to work. I am trying to generate those six specific permutations of four elements, not all 24 of them. Sure, I wouldn't use $a and $b in production code, I trimmed down my code so as to keep my question as simple as I could make it.

Comment: Perhaps you should write a question about why you cannot get array references to work.

Answer (score 9):

I might go with subs.

```perl
my @e = (
   sub { @_[ 0,1, 2,3 ] },
   sub { @_[ 0,2, 1,3 ] },
   sub { @_[ 0,3, 1,2 ] },
   sub { @_[ 1,2, 0,3 ] },
   sub { @_[ 1,3, 0,2 ] },
   sub { @_[ 2,3, 0,1 ] },
);

...

for (@e) {
   my ( $a,$b, $c,$d ) = $_->($i, $j, $k, $l);
   ...
}
```

If the values were already in an array, the above simplifies to the following:

```perl
my @e = (
   [ 0,1, 2,3 ],
   [ 0,2, 1,3 ],
   [ 0,3, 1,2 ],
   [ 1,2, 0,3 ],
   [ 1,3, 0,2 ],
   [ 2,3, 0,1 ],
);

...

for (@e) {
   my ( $a,$b, $c,$d ) = @v[$_];
   ...
}
```

If we were dealing with more values, I'd consider a programmatic approach to generating the *pair*mutations, but I can't think of something simple enough to be worthwhile.

Comment: Thank you!  Your "subs" code answers my question, and works.  (It also runs significantly faster than my "eval" code.)

Answer (score 4):

Do not reinvent the wheel. To loop through all permutations of an array, use any of the Perl modules written for this purpose, such as [Algorithm::Permute](https://metacpan.org/pod/Algorithm::Permute) (this is pointed out in the comment by Håkon Hægland).

For example:

```
use Algorithm::Permute;
use feature qw( say );

my $perm = new Algorithm::Permute([$i, $j, $k, $l]);

while (@permutation = $perm->next) {
   say join "\t", @permutation;
}
```

Comment: Yes, if I were trying to loop through all permutations, that is what I would do. But I only want to loop through six of them. I'm partitioning the elements into an ordered pair of unordered pairs.

Answer (score 3):

I do not know what exactly you want to achieve, but this might help you:

```
my @e = ( [$i,$j, $k,$l],  [$i,$k, $j,$l],  [$i,$l, $j,$k],
          [$j,$k, $i,$l],  [$j,$l, $i,$k],  [$k,$l, $i,$j]
        );

...

foreach (@e) {
    my ($a,$b, $c,$d) = @$_;
    ...
```

`@e` is now an array of array references. In the `foreach` loop `$_` contains always one of the array references and `@$_` dereferences it, resulting in the array.

This has a slightly different semantics because `$i`, `$j`, `$k` and `$l` will be evaluated only once when `@e` is assigned. This may be ok, but it can be a problem in your application.

If you need your original behaviour, you can do it using a slightly more complicated solution:

```
my @e = ( [\$i,\$j, \$k,\$l],  [\$i,\$k, \$j,\$l],  [\$i,\$l, \$j,\$k],
          [\$j,\$k, \$i,\$l],  [\$j,\$l, \$i,\$k],  [\$k,\$l, \$i,\$j]
        );

...

foreach (@e) {
    my ($a,$b, $c,$d) = map {$$_} @$_;
    ...
```

This means, `@e` holds references on the variables and they will be dereferenced by `map {$$_}`.

By the way, you should consider to make a sub out of the body of the foreach loop.

Comment: That looks promising. But the problem with this is, $i etc. get dereferenced when @e is declared, not when the foreach statement is executed.

Comment: @user36956 yes, this is right. It has a slightly different semantics. It may be ok, depending on the context. I do not know what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by "dereferenced" in this case. In your code, do the values of the variables `$i` through `$l` change between loop iterations? I suspect that Donat's suggestion of making a sub of the foreach loop is best then, then it is a simple fix to just run the sub with the variables directly, instead of using an `@e` array as intermediate storage. E,g, `do_foreach($i, $j, $k, $l); do_foreach($i, $k, $j, $l);` etc.

Comment: I have a sneaky suspicion that your line of questioning comes from suffering from an XY-problem, i.e. an error earlier on that you are trying to patch this way.

Answer (score 0):

As I seem to be able to glean from the comments, is that the values of `$i $j $k $l` change during the foreach loop, and you need to use their current value. Which is the reason for the somewhat insane `eval()` solution.

Other people have suggested solutions that you have not accepted, so maybe **this** is what you need. As [Donat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10533011/donat) says in his answer, you can make a sub of the foreach loop. This way you can run the foreach loop without the intermediate storage in the `@e` array. Of course, this would rely on altering global variables inside the sub, which generally is a bad thing.

```
do_foreach($i, $j, $k, $l);
do_foreach($i, $k, $j, $l);
do_foreach($i, $l, $j, $k);
...etc

sub do_foreach {
    my ($a, $b, $c, $d) = @_;
    ... do stuff
}
```

I suspect that your problems come from a poor design decision elsewhere in your code else that it might benefit from resolving. But it is hard to tell with the information given.

Answer (score 0):

If you indeed want to process only those permutation referred in your sample code, then why not do it as following (square numbers for permutations)?

NOTE: please clarify you problem in more details and white minimal code sample which could be run (do not forget about `use strict; use warnings` -- two *magic* lines which assist to avoid many pitfalls)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my($i,$j,$k,$l) = (1..4);

my @e = ( [$i,$j, $k,$l],  [$i,$k, $j,$l],  [$i,$l, $j,$k],
          [$j,$k, $i,$l],  [$j,$l, $i,$k],  [$k,$l, $i,$j]
        );
        
do_work($_) for @e;

sub do_work {
    my $aref = shift;
    
    my @square = map { $_*$_ } @{$aref};
    
    say join "\t", @square;
}
```

Output

```
1       4       9       16
1       9       4       16
1       16      4       9
4       9       1       16
4       16      1       9
9       16      1       4
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure why you have only 6 permutations. Please study the following piece of code for compliance with your problem.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my @array = qw/a b c d/;

my $result = mutate(\@array);

say join "\t", @{$_} for @{$result};

sub mutate {
    my $aref = shift;
    my @data = @{$aref};
    my @ret;
    
    for ( 1..scalar @data ) {
        my($c,@block) = @data;
        for ( 1..scalar @block ) {
            push @ret,[$c,@block];
            my $t = pop @block;
            unshift @block, $t;
        }
        @data = (@block,$c);
    }
    
    return \@ret;
}
```

Output

```
a       b       c       d
a       d       b       c
a       c       d       b
b       c       d       a
b       a       c       d
b       d       a       c
c       d       a       b
c       b       d       a
c       a       b       d
d       a       b       c
d       c       a       b
d       b       c       a
```

Other sample for `my @array = qw/a b c d e/;`

```
a       b       c       d       e
a       e       b       c       d
a       d       e       b       c
a       c       d       e       b
b       c       d       e       a
b       a       c       d       e
b       e       a       c       d
b       d       e       a       c
c       d       e       a       b
c       b       d       e       a
c       a       b       d       e
c       e       a       b       d
d       e       a       b       c
d       c       e       a       b
d       b       c       e       a
d       a       b       c       e
e       a       b       c       d
e       d       a       b       c
e       c       d       a       b
e       b       c       d       a
```

Comment: I don't understand the point of this answer. OP does not need all permutations, so you are suggesting _another_ way to _not_ generate all permutations? Your algorithm does not generate all permutations: there should be _n!_ permutations of _n_ elements. On your first example, you are missing `a b d c` for instance...

Comment: @Data - permutation in my understanding is all possible combinations, OP was not clear initially in his post (my telepathic ability is limited in reading his mind). You are correct that I missed some combinations, my omission -- it was awhile when I studied and programmed something of this kind. Thank you for pointing it out. I offered OP other solution for subset permutations he has indicated in the code.

Comment: @Dada -- perhaps, I will need to find a time to look how to implement *mutation* to account for all possible combinations (just for my mind exercise).